# .order() by attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

Every answer has a `:votes_count` attribute and i'm trying to order by that count my answers.

I tried

```
def index
  @answers = Answer.all.order("votes_count desc")
end
```

but i think i'm missing something here.

Comment: well you don't need the 'all' but that doesn't change anything.  What's the order you're getting instead?  id?

Comment: The problem was, that i was calling it at a wrong point.. I updated my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Answer.order("votes_count desc")
Answer.order(:votes_count).reverse
```

Either should work.

**EDIT**

You can do what you described by:

```
@answers = Answer.order("votes_count desc")
@toggled = @answers.where(accept_toggle: true)
@answers = @toggled + (@answers - @toggled)
```

This will put all the answers that have `accept_toggle == true` at the front of the array, followed by all the other answers sorted by `votes_count`